# Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages. - Symfony Project

Tags: php, symfony, dependencies, composer-php

I try to install the dependencies from a project I have to maintain, but every time I try to do a composer install I get this error '**Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.**' and it gives me this error:

```
    Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
    Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony v3.4.23 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.4.23].
    - don't install symfony/css-selector v4.2.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.23
    - Installation request for symfony/css-selector v4.2.4 -> satisfiable by symfony/css-selector[v4.2.4].
```

I've tried changing composer.json, doing composer update --lock, composer install, composer update

Here I paste the composer.json with the dependencies.

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=7.1",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^1.0",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
        "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "^1.5",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0.19",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1.0",
        "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3.10",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.4.*",
        "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "^4.2",
        "symfony/css-selector": "^4.2",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^4.2"
    },
```

I am unable to start the app beacuse of the autoload.php that comes along with one of the dependencies.

I have the last PHP version and the last composer version.

Thank you very much.

PS: Tried deleting composer.lock and doing again composer install and composer update and this is the result:

```
 Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.31
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.30
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.29
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.28
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.27
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.26
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.25
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.24
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.23
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.22
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.21
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.20
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.19
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.18
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.17
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.16
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.15
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.14
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.13
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.12
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.11
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.10
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.9
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.8
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.7
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.6
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.5
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.4
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.3
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.2
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.1
    - don't install symfony/css-selector v4.2.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.0
    - don't install symfony/css-selector v4.2.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.0
    - don't install symfony/css-selector v4.2.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.0
    - don't install symfony/css-selector v4.2.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.0
    - don't install symfony/css-selector v4.2.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.0
    - don't install symfony/css-selector v4.2.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.0
    - don't install symfony/css-selector v4.2.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.0
    - don't install symfony/css-selector v4.2.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.0
    - don't install symfony/css-selector v4.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.0
    - don't install symfony/css-selector v4.2.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.0
    - don't install symfony/css-selector v4.2.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.0
    - don't install symfony/css-selector v4.2.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.0
    - don't install symfony/css-selector v4.3.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.0
    - don't install symfony/css-selector v4.3.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.0
    - don't install symfony/css-selector v4.3.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.0
    - don't install symfony/css-selector v4.3.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.0
    - don't install symfony/css-selector v4.3.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.0
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony 3.4.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.4.0, v3.4.1, v3.4.10, v3.4.11, v3.4.12, v3.4.13, v3.4.14, v3.4.15, v3.4.16, v3.4.17, v3.4.18, v3.4.19, v3.4.2, v3.4.20, v3.4.21, v3.4.22, v3.4.23, v3.4.24, v3.4.25, v3.4.26, v3.4.27, v3.4.28, v3.4.29, v3.4.3, v3.4.30, v3.4.31, v3.4.4, v3.4.5, v3.4.6, v3.4.7, v3.4.8, v3.4.9].
    - Installation request for symfony/css-selector ^4.2 -> satisfiable by symfony/css-selector[v4.2.0, v4.2.1, v4.2.10, v4.2.11, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9, v4.3.0, v4.3.1, v4.3.2, v4.3.3, v4.3.4].
```

Comment: Delete the `composer.lock` file, then try again.

Comment: @aynber nope, not working, it gives me a lot of "don't install symfony/symfony"

Comment: try to run `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: @Joseph nothing neither, the same problems

Comment: amm try `composer update` it should works

Comment: @Joseph still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is caused by combination of these two requirements:

```
"symfony/symfony": "3.4.*"
"symfony/css-selector": "^4.2"
```

Symfony/symfony package has symfony/css-selector in it's `replace` section with `self.version` That means when composer tries to instal `symfony/symfony` version 3.4.31 it also counts as `symfony/css-selector` version 3.4.31 which doesn't match the version ^4.2 in your require-dev.

You might also encouter same problem with `symfony/browser-kit`.

You should revise your requirements to not include multiple versions of same package.

Comment: How could I do that? I'm new to Symfony and the packages managing. Thanks..

Comment: I would suggest removing those problematic packages from require-dev. But i can't say what exactly will happen because i don't know why someone put them there in first place.

Comment: Thank you, I've deleted them and everything works now. I hope nothing new appears. :)

Answer (score 2):

This error means that there is some package incompatibility in your composer.json file. If you want to force, run  `composer install --ignore-platform-reqs`

But I suggest you to check wich dependencies version are not compatible with each other